# Form Recognizer Http Request

Tags: rpa, azure-form-recognizer

I am new with Form Recognizer offered by Azure (Using Rest API) and I am implementing it with UI Path (RPA Tool) upon sending a post request i am getting a status code of zero(0).

Answer (score 0):

Could you share info on:

1. The API/operation your are sending the request against.
2. User-agent where the request is being sent from.
3. Type of input (and if it is non-PII and shareable a sample would be great).

Any other detail that might be relevant to narrow down the issue.